# ORC specifying serializer is not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql, orc

I have some data in HDFS that was imported using Sqoop. The data was imported as ORC and compression is Snappy.

I am trying to create a table on top of this data with the following DDL statement. However, I am getting the following error.

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10043]: Either list of columns or a
>   custom serializer should be specified

However, I am defining the "custom serializer" by defining `ROW FORMAT SERDE and STORED AS INPUTFORMAT and OUTPUTFORMAT`

DDL STATEMENT:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_db.my_table_orc
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  '/hdfs/app/DL/ORC_DATA_LOCATION'
tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive currently cannot support creation of an ORC table without specifying the column list in the DDL.  ORC files do contain metadata about the columns though, so if you're unsure of a given ORC file's columns, then you can run the [ORC File Dump Utility](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-ORCFileDumpUtility) to get it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the table's columns.
2. No need for input/output format. `stored as orc` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Defining the columns by hand will take a long time. My table is very wide, lots of columns :)

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7042/orc-table-creation-without-column-details.html